# Insert missing date in the given date range per user

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have table called tblprocesstimekeeping which have a following data below:

[image]

Let's say I have a date range **2019-05-01 - 2019-05-15**

What I'm trying to do is to insert the missing date between the given range within the data on the tblprocesstimekeeping per empCompID.

Here's My code:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2019-05-01'); // Get Begin Date
$end = new DateTime('2019-05-15'); // Get End Date
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); // Increment +1 Day

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end); // Get Date Range


foreach($daterange as $date){

    $dateNumber = $date->format("Y-m-d"); // counter date + 1 day

    //Select company access id and date from tblprocesstimekeeping
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblprocesstimekeeping where companyAccessID = '$companyAccessID'");                
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){ 

            $empCompID = $row->empCompID;
            $date = $row->date;                     
            //echo $date .' = '. $empCompID.'<br>';

            if ($date == $dateNumber) {
                echo $date .' = '. $empCompID.' = GOOD <br>';
            } else{
                echo $dateNumber .' = '. $empCompID.' = NO DATA <br>';
            }




    }                   



}
```

The output should be:

```
2019-05-01 = 11007 - NO DATA
2019-05-01 = 20003 - NO DATA
2019-05-02 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-02 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-03 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-03 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-04 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-04 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-05 = 11007 - NO DATA
2019-05-05 = 20003 - NO DATA
2019-05-06 = 11007 - NO DATA
2019-05-06 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-07 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-07 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-08 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-08 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-09 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-09 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-10 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-10 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-11 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-11 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-12 = 11007 - NO DATA
2019-05-12 = 20003 - NO DATA
2019-05-13 = 11007 - NO DATA
2019-05-13 = 20003 - NO DATA
2019-05-14 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-14 = 20003 - GOOD
2019-05-15 = 11007 - GOOD
2019-05-15 = 20003 - GOOD
```

But Instead Im getting this output:

```
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-01 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-05 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-12 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-13 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = NO DATA 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = GOOD
```

**EDIT:**

IF I change my query into this

```
SELECT * FROM tblprocesstimekeeping where companyAccessID = '$companyAccessID' and date='$dateNumber'
```

It only show this output:

```
2019-05-02 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-02 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-03 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-03 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-04 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-04 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-06 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-07 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-07 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-08 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-08 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-09 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-09 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-10 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-10 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-11 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-11 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-14 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-14 = 20003 = GOOD 
2019-05-15 = 11007 = GOOD 
2019-05-15 = 20003 = GOOD
```

The missing date still not showing..

Comment: Why is `$dateNumber` not part of your query?

Comment: What I do is to select all data from the table then get the date from each user ID then if the date is not equal it should echo the missing date.. is my query wrong sir? :(

Comment: Why would you want to insert/store this ?

Comment: That's my plan sir. But I've only show the basic scenario for not getting the correct data for the missing date.

Comment: @dharman Thank you.. But that's just an example I wil do the querying in CI after I get the correct logic.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see a point in doing the same thing again. Do it correct from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is your problem:** you are creating rows in your table that do not exist. For the day that is not in the table, you are creating a row that indicates an absence of a row in the table.

This makes this problem a little tricky in the approach that you took. You could construct a complex MYSQL query to handle this or could process it in PHP.

The better way to do this is going through all users and each day.

```php
// List of all users to find
$users = ['11007', '20003'];

foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    // Get date in database format
    $dateNumber = $date->format("Y-m-d"); // counter date + 1 day

    // Go through all users
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        // Find all accesses for that user and day
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblprocesstimekeeping WHERE companyAccessID = '$companyAccessID' AND empCompID = '$user' AND date = '$dateNumber'");

        // If there is a row, then paste it, otherwise past NO DATA
        if ($query->num_rows()) {
            echo $dateNumber.' = '.$user->id.' = GOOD <br>';
        } else {
            echo $dateNumber.' = '.$user->id.' = NO DATA <br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've that sir but it only echo this one:

`echo $date .' = '. $empCompID.' = GOOD <br>';`

Comment: Let me know if that is functional.

Comment: Im getting this error sir.. `Call to a member function num_rows() on array`

Comment: Nice one sir! I've just edt your answer for minimal error.. Thank you again sir!

Comment: One more thing sir. how can I insert all the user id from my table into array?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is incorrect.
As you are not filtering the table data by date, for each date in the date range you are selecting all rows in the tblprocesstimekeeping table, and printing result for all off them (that’s why you have 21 rows for each date).

I’m not familar with php so I will not post code here but here are my sujestions:

First you need to known the ids of the employees 
You can get them from the data base with this query:

```
“select distinct empCompId from FROM tblprocesstimekeeping where companyAccessID = '$companyAccessID'"
```

and save them someware (in an array perhaps)

then, to accomplish what you want, you will need to perform two cicles

```
// first iterate by date
foreach($daterange as $date)
  // then, for each date iterate by employee
    foreach($employees as $empId){
     // check existance on record
     If (exists on data base)
        Echo ‘good’
    else
        echo ‘nodata’
```

For the “check existance in database” you can simply change you query to filter table data by date and

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblprocesstimekeeping where companyAccessID = '$companyAccessID' and date='$dateNumber'
 ");
```

But you should have this into account:

You are making as many consecutive calls to the database as the dates in your date range.

If possible, consider an algorithm that makes **only one call to the datadate** and returns all the data from the start to end of your date range (before the for foreach $daterange cicle)
And them you simple filter that data to check the existence for a particular date on code.

If the number of record involved are not that high (here you have only 21) the performance with this solution will be much, much better

Comment: Thank you. I'll take note with that sir,

Answer (score 0):

I thought about your problem and I think I have a better solution.

Create a stored procedure to do all the work for you.

This will create a stored procedure that has parameters to pass the company identifier, the start and end date of the date range you want to display, and returns the result you want (date, employeeid and a flag 'found' that returns 0 when there is no record no the tblprocesstimekeeping table or 1 if it exists.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myListing //

CREATE PROCEDURE myListing(companyId int, startdate date, endDate date)
BEGIN
  WITH RECURSIVE days(day) AS 
  (
    select startdate  UNION ALL 
    select DATE_ADD(day,INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM days WHERE day<= endDate 
  )
  select days.day as date, Employees.Id as empCompId, case when Time.date IS NULL THEN 0 else 1 end as found
  FROM days
  cross join 
  (select distinct empCompId as Id from tblprocesstimekeeping where companyAccessID = companyId and date >= startdate and date <= endDate) AS Employees
  LEFT JOIN
  (select * from tblprocesstimekeeping where companyAccessID = companyId and date >= startdate and date <= endDate) AS Time on days.day = Time.date and Employees.Id = Time.empCompId
  order by days.day, Employees.Id;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you'll only need to call it passing the parameters you want and iterate trough the result and printing data depending on that flag found.

```
set @startdate  = '2019-05-01';
set @endDate  = '2019-05-15';
set @companyId = 1;

CALL myListing(@companyId, @startdate, @enddate);
```

Se DBfiddler [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cQmzvygDto5S3b2DuBpzAZ/0)